# "Bad Gateway" error using Python requests module with multipart encoded file POST

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

I am getting the error message "Bad Gateway

The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server" with the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://apis.company.com/v3/media"
attachments = 'media': ('x.mp3', open('x.mp3', 'r'))}
headers = {'content-type': "multipart/form-data",'cache-control': "no-cache" 
          'Authorization':"Bearer zzz" }
response = requests.post(url, files=attachments, headers = headers)
print response.text
```

I'm following the example in the requests Quickstart documentation, where it says "You can also pass a list of tuples to the data argument": http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Goyo if I change "files" to "data", as in data = attachments, it doesn't change the error message. The client I'm using stipulates this:  response = requests.post(
   self.client.url + '/media',
   headers = headers,
   files = attachments)

Comment: Do you want to pass a `data` argument, a `files` argument or are you just throwing arguments at random?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that I set the content-type in the header. This code works:

```
    import requests

    url = 'https://apis.company.com/v3/media'
    token = 'token-goes-here'

    headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token }

    filename = 'x.mp3'

    with open(filename, 'rb') as media_file:

    attachments = {
'media': (filename, media_file, 'application/octet-stream')
 }

    response = requests.post(url, files = attachments, headers = headers)

    print response.text
```